# Could the "post-forcing continuum" be a new cardinality?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

*This question is vaguely related to [this MO question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192314/a-new-cardinality-living-in-every-forcing-extension).*

Suppose $V$ is a (for simplicity, well-founded) model of $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a forcing notion in $V$, and let $G$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$. My question is whether a certain "new cardinality" phenomenon can occur:

> Could it be the case that $V[G]\models$ "There is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}$ and any $x\in V$"?

One wrinkle here is that $V[G]$ need not satisfy $\mathsf{AD}$ anymore; indeed, [preserving $\mathsf{AD}$ is quite hard](https://mathoverflow.net/a/325782/8133). So $\mathsf{AD}$ doesn't give us a lot of "leverage" in the forcing extension that I can see.

*I would be happy to replace $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ with any stronger (consistent :P) theory; in particular, it might be easier to get a negative answer for something more "canonical" like $\mathsf{ZF+AD}+V=L(\mathbb{R})$.*

---

Here are a couple quick comments:

On the one hand, to preempt worries about triviality note that we can have $V[G]\models$ "There is some $a$ which is not in bijection with any $b\in V$." For example, [Monro showed](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/on-generic-extensions-without-the-axiom-of-choice1/D2CAA61A488CD4A3644F272CBF6DB969) that we can have an amorphous set in $V[G]$ even if there are no amorphous sets in $V$; since amorphousness is downwards-absolute, any amorphous set in such a $V[G]$ is not (in $V[G]$, anyways) in bijection with any set in $V$. *(This reference was pointed out to me by Asaf Karagila.)*

On the other hand, questions of this type are always trivial over $\mathsf{ZFC}$ for the following reason:

- Forcing preserves choice, so $V[G]\models\mathsf{ZFC}$.
- That means that for every name $\nu$ we have in $V[G]$ that $\nu[G]$ is in bijection with some ordinal $\alpha\in Ord^{V[G]}$.
- But $Ord^V=Ord^{V[G]}$, so $V[G]$ sees a bijection between $\nu[G]$ and some set in $V$.

On the other other hand, the previous hand's argument is quite fragile and I don't see that it gives any insight into my question. Specifically, the third bulletpoint is crucial but has no relevant analogue for the $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$-setting that I can see.

Comment: There is always a surjection from a ground model object.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Certainly, but that doesn't (seem to) get me a *bi*jection. (For other readers: for every name $\nu$ there is in $V[G]$ a surjection $\nu\rightarrow\nu[G]$. Basically, send $\langle \pi,p\rangle\in\nu$ to $\pi[G]$ if $p\in G$, and to some random element of $\nu[G]$ otherwise. Of course this assumes $\nu[G]\not=\emptyset$; the remaining case is a good exercise :P.)