# Comparing the cardinalities of generic $\mathbb{R}$s

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

This is yet another question about cardinalities in forcing extensions of models of $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$ (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767428/could-the-post-forcing-continuum-be-a-new-cardinality)). Specificially, I think I've isolated the simplest question which I can't yet answer. I suspect this is actually quite easy and I'm just having a silly moment, but currently I don't see the argument:

> Suppose $V$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$. Let $c,d$ be mutually Cohen generic over $V$; is there in $V[c,d]$ a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^{V[c]}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{V[d]}$?

*Note that a negative answer to the above-linked question in the case of Cohen forcing would give a positive answer to this question.*

"Obviously" the answer should be **yes**, but I don't see how to prove that. We have a set $\mathcal{X}\in V$ of names for reals such that every real in a Cohen extension is named by some element of $\mathcal{X}$, and each Cohen real $a$ induces an equivalence relation $\sim_a$ on $\mathcal{X}$ as $\nu\sim_a\mu\leftrightarrow\nu[a]=\mu[a]$. So really this question is asking for a bijection in $V[c,d]$ between $\mathcal{X}/\sim_c$ and $\mathcal{X}/\sim_d$. Intuitively this should exist since Cohen forcing is as homogeneous as one could hope; however, in the absence of choice in $V[c,d]$ I don't actually see how to build one.

EDIT: While it's not my main question, I'd also be interested in a weak *negative* result: are there $M\models\mathsf{ZF}$ and mutually-Cohen-over-$M$ reals $c,d$ such that $M[c,d]\models \mathbb{R}^{M[c]}\not\equiv\mathbb{R}^{M[d]}$? I am really interested in the determinacy case, but any sort of pathology like this would be quite cool.

---

To preempt one natural attempt, note that [Cohen forcing kills determinacy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/325782/8133) so we can't use determinacy in $V[c,d]$ even though we have it in $V$. While at first glance this might appear to contradict (say) the generic absoluteness of the theory of $L(\mathbb{R})$ given large cardinals, there is no discrepancy since $(L(\mathbb{R}))^V[G]\not=(L(\mathbb{R}))^{V[G]}$ in general.

Comment: Nice question. *Real* nice. You're really making it hard to focus on research.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I live to displease!

Comment: Here's a strategy: use the fact you can change any initial segment of $d$ without changing the model (i.e. the homogeneity, but dressed in a more semantic way) to argue that if $\mu[a]=\nu[a]$, there is some initial segment forcing that, and therefore this may also happen in $V[d]$ by swapping a sufficiently long initial segment. (There's probably a gaping hole in the argument, but it's a start. I gotta go make dinner.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how to make that work, since swapping segments to create one equality will generally break another.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep posting bounties on these questions. The real bounty is the paper you can surely write from any kind of useful answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But *I* currently cannot write a useful answer, hence cannot write such a paper. (Really in retrospect I should have asked this at MO, but having asked it at MSE I feel bad moving it to MO without bountying it here first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move this off the unanswered queue, I'll observe that [Paul Larson gave a negative answer at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/392486/8133). (I've made this CW to avoid reputation gain.)